# First split then slice value

Tags: jquery

I know how to split a value using deliminators. I also know how to slice a value to remove the last couple chars. I need to combine these now, which is the part I can't figure out.

```
    $("#product").val(value.split('|')[0]);
```

How would I add `slice(0,-1)` to this function above? I want it to first split, then slice.

So the result would be everything before the '|' and minus one char

**Solved:**

```
$("#product").val(value.split('|')[0].slice(0, -1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean slice the 1st element from array?

Try below,

```
 $("#product").val(value.split('|')[0].slice(0, -1))
```

Comment: No, that was  typo in my title there - should have said slice instead of splice - sorry

Comment: @mcflause What is it you want?

Comment: input=Widget1|Widget2    output=Widget

Comment: @mcflause Thx.. but u had 99% figured out.. just needed some attempts

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var val = value.split('|')[0].slice(0, -1)     
$("#product").val(val);
```